# How to make search results open specific pages depending on search criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

This is a search function that pulls information depending on search criteria and prints it in a table. Also I have a few different pages for different restaurants that I want to open depending on what dish i click on. Basically, when I click on the href I want it to recognize which specific restaurant it is and take me there.

This is my code:

```
<%
        String value=request.getParameter("search");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("**************", "******", "*******");
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT menu.name, menu.info, menu.price, restaurants.name from menu,"
                + " restaurants where restaurants_restaurantID=RestaurantID AND (menu.name like '%"
                + value
                + "%' "
                + "or menu.info like '%"
                + value
                + "%' or menu.category like '%"
                + value
                + "%' "
                + "or menu.kitchen like '%"
                + value
                + "%' or quick_choose like '%" + value + "%')");
    %>
        <table>
        <tr class="head">
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td>Info:</td>
          <td>Price:</td>
          <td>Restaurant:</td>
          <td>Location:</td>
         
        </tr>    
      <%
      
       while (rs.next()){ 
      %>
        <tr class="content">
          <td class="name"><%=rs.getString("name")%></td>
          <td class="info"><%=rs.getString("info")%></td>
          <td class="price"><%=rs.getInt("price")%></td>
          <td class="restaurant"><%=rs.getString("restaurants.name")%></td>
          <td class="location"><a href="#" %>>Show</a>
          
        </tr>
      <%
       }
      %>
      </table>

    <%conn.close();%>

    </div>
```

Comment: What's the relationship between the output of `getString("info")` and the endpoint URL? Is there any?

Comment: Sorry, that was not supposed to be there..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. Here you can click on the restaurant name to go to the respective page

```
  <%
  while (rs.next()){ 
  %>
    <tr class="content">
      <td class="name"><%=rs.getString("name")%></td>
      <td class="info"><%=rs.getString("info")%></td>
      <td class="price"><%=rs.getInt("price")%></td>
      <td class="restaurant"><%=rs.getString("restaurants.name")%></td>
      <td class="location"><a href="ShowRestaurant.jsp?restoid=<%=rs.getString("name")%>">Show</a>

    </tr>
  <%
   }
  %>
```

Now in the `ShowRestaurant.jsp` page use the following code to get the restaurant name

```
request.getParameter("restoid")
```

Then get the data from the database and display as you did on the main page

Here I am assuming that

1. the `"name"` of your restaurant is unique.
2. `ShowRestaurant.jsp?restoid=resto1` will display the details of
   `resto1`

Comment: Okay. Are there supposed to be two "getString" statements?

Comment: Updated my code to avoid confusion. Now new page will open on click of show link.

Comment: Yes, exactly, thank you. Any idea on how to go from here? I have 5 separate HTML pages that i want to link with the "show" button.

Comment: Can you add some more details like "What is the unique id?", "What you mean by 5 different Pages?" etc

Comment: Well, if i search for example "pizza" i will get say 5 dishes that belongs to a pizzeria and if i click "show" on any of them i want the information page of the pizzeria to be displayed.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check

Comment: Its working so far, thank you. But I was wondering now if you know how to make the ShowRestaurant.jsp display the different pages depending on what URL the "show" button gives me? Sorry if my question is unclear.

Comment: As I mentioned use `request.getParameter("restoid")` for getting the restaurant name. For now just add <%=request.getParameter("restoid") %> in ShowRestaurant.jsp and check the result. You will come to know whats next...